# Как сделать счётчик времени на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В `JS` не силён, помогите сделать счётчик на нём.

Нужно, чтобы по клику на ссылку запускался таймер и начинал считать до указанного времени, и после выводил, например, сообщение Helo world

Забыл сказать,этот счетчик будет запускаться по несколько раз без перезагрузки страницы.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое: [setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/settimeout)

```
function hello_world() {
    alert("Hello, World");
}
setTimeout(hello_world, 1000);
```

Через 1 секунду выведется сообщение "Hello, World"

Comment: Спасибо, но с setTimeout чет я не подружился. А ответ я уже нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на свой же вопрос, может кому пригодится.

```
function timer() {

        var seconds = 20;

        var seconds_timer_id = setInterval(function() {
            if (seconds > 0) {
                seconds --;
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }
                $(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } else {
                clearInterval(seconds_timer_id);    
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

И ссылка кликнув на которую запустится таймер

```
<a href="#" onClick="timer();">Запуск таймера</a>
```

А тут будет отображаться отсчет

```
<span class="seconds">20</span>
```

Comment: обратите внимание, что каждое нажатие кнопки запустит _новый_ таймер, причем остановится в итоге _только_ один

Answer (score 1):

Ну или так, используя `setTimeout()`.
Вводишь количество секунд и по истечению времени выводится "**HELLO WORLD**"

```js
var ticks;

function startTimer() {
  ticks = document.getElementById("nTicks").value;
  letsGo();
}

function letsGo() {
  if(ticks<0) {
       document.getElementById("tick").innerHTML='HELLO WORLD!';      
       return;
  }

  document.getElementById("tick").innerHTML=ticks;
  ticks--;
  setTimeout(letsGo,1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="tick"></div>
<input id="nTicks">
<a href="#" onclick="startTimer()">НАЧАТЬ</a>
```